# When Running Cubevalue formulas the data model starts refreshing on the background

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot, cube, olap-cube

I'm using the cubevalue formulas to access a large database of 14M rows (loaded to the data model), but I need to manipulate the data via macros/VBA to meet my goals, that's why I was in need of use Cubevalue formulas, somehow I was able to uncheck the "Enable Background Refresh" box option of the "ThisWorkbookDataModel" connection as well as the rest of them that are connected to the workbook, but when I run the VBA subroutine that basically copy and paste the formulas on new sheets and VBA finish running then the data model starts refreshing on the background and it takes forever.

1. I want to know what I need to do so the Data Model will not refresh in the background so the cubevalue formulas can turn to their final value once I turn the workbook calculation to automatic.
2. If nothing can be done regarding the first request, then I would like to know if there is any VBA code that can tell me if the data model is being refreshed in the background (even if that feature is disabled) so I when I try to run another macro I can ask it to wait until there is nothing refreshing on the background.

I don't want to refresh all queries since the source is of 14M rows so Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone will take forever.

I already tried to calculate the cubevalue formulas individually but seems very inefficient, I need to be able to do this without the datamodel background refreshing, or if this is needed then I would like to know the status so I can ask the next subroutine to wait till data model finish refreshing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.